# Unable to uninstall old Docker version

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I've got some old versions of Docker (1.12.3, 17.05.0-ce) installed on a couple of machines, but would like to upgrade to the latest CE version.  I tried following the [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#uninstall-old-versions):  `sudo apt-get remove docker` (I don't have docker-engine or docker.io installed), but I get an error: `Package 'docker' is not installed, so not removed`.  It was so long ago I don't remember the installation procedure I used.  The instruction go on to say "It’s OK if `apt-get` reports that none of these packages are installed.", but I wanted to check and see if anyone has encountered this issue before, and if so, were you able to update successfully / without any conflicts?  I just want to make sure that it is truly safe to proceed with the update.  Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go ahead and give it a try on the machine running version 1.12.3, despite the error about not finding the package, and everything is working as expected.  Looks like the documentation is correct and the error about the package not being installed can be safely ignored.  Just wanted to share in case others had the same concern!  Thanks!